# Python Pandas Dataframe: Take Greatest Value Smaller Than

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python, I have a pandas dataframe. I want to filter for one value of column `A`.

I am looking for the row, where column `A` is the highest value that is smaller than '5' (so if column `A` does have values '1', '2', '4', '7', it should be '4'). Another condition exists, too.

The following statement does not work.

How do I have to change it with regards to the maximum condition, so that it is working?

```
df_new = df[(df['some_other_column'] < XYZ) & max(df['A'] <= '5')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.searchsorted` -

```
df

   x
0  1
1  2
2  4
3  7

df.iloc[(np.searchsorted(df.x.values, 5) - 1).clip(0)]

   x
2  4
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : np.arange(100000)})
```

```
%%timeit 
x = df.x
g = x[x <= 12345].max()
df[x == g]

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit df.iloc[(np.searchsorted(df.x.values, 12345) - 1).clip(0)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 139 µs per loop
```

There's no comparison, using `searchsorted` is much faster.

Comment: Isn't this using an assumption of the column being sorted though?

Comment: Indeed. But you can fix that with minimal trouble if you pass argsorted indices to the function as the “sorter” argument.

Comment: It also return at most one row, which might not be desirable. Also could you please update your answer with the sorter and add a `np.random.permutation` to x column in the generation part, I am curious as to how to optimise this bit when the index is exactly equal to the value.

Comment: Also a note, the iloc argument will have to be modified if you want to pull a specific column value out when you are in a mutli-column dataframe.  Using this would pull a series.

Comment: @Jon not quite! While this method works for both Series and frames, it returns all columns for frames unless you specify a list of column names/positions as the second argument to loc/iloc.

Answer (score 3):

The other condition doesn't really relate to the underlying question, so I am going to ignore it.

The following does the trick (pardon the poor variable naming):-

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 4, 7]})
   ...: x = df['x']
   ...: greatest_smaller_than_5 = x[x <= 5].max()
   ...: df[df['x'] == greatest_smaller_than_5]
   ...: 
Out[1]: 
   x
2  4
```

P.S. In your question, it says `smaller than`, yet your code suggests it's `smaller or equal to`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, closer to the conditional syntax you were originally attempting, that uses the dedicated pandas function idxmax():

```
idx = df[df['A'] <= 5].idxmax() 

desired_row = df.loc[idx]
```